# Is Anychart capable of font label resizing. How can I make the fonts scalable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, anychart

I have several Anychart charts and maps that will be resized from full sized monitors to smart phones. The shapes resize fine, but the fonts do not. I haven't been able to find any documentation on this on the Anychart site.

Here is the basic script I'm currently using for formatting:

```js
var firstSeries = usMap.choropleth(firstDataSetForSeries);
    firstSeries.geoIdField("code_hasc").overlapMode("allow-overlap");
    firstSeries.color("#e89498").hatchFill("percent05", "#866163", 1, 9).hovered({fill:"#f0b2b5"}).selected({fill:"#e89498"});
    firstSeries.labels().enabled(true).fontSize(13).fontColor('#000').fontWeight('bold').format(function(){
return this.value;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

To have the font size adjust to a size of the window, you could use a function provided below

```
// change font size on load
let font = 11;
let width = 720;
function getFontsByScreenWidth(actualFontSize, maxScreenWidth){
  return (actualFontSize / maxScreenWidth) * window.innerWidth;
};

// enable and customize the series labels
series
    .labels()
    .fontSize(getFontsByScreenWidth(font, width));
```

and in this sample: https://playground.anychart.com/j4yjf9TV/1